# Exponential-Golomb Decoder in Python (Codewars)

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, exponential

I am trying to pass one of the Codewars challenge ,,Exponential-Golomb Decoder" here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e4d8a53b499e20016b018a0/swift

The idea is to take input in binary format:"001000000101111001010001101" -> 00100 000010111 1 00101 0001101

and return list of decoded numbers:[3, 22, 0, 4, 12]

If You give the **Sentence** of for example **00100 00101**, let's see that You start with 2 leading zeros, then hit **1**, and so the first resulted number is **number of zeros + 1 + number of zeros** (00+1+00), let's say the Length of this number is **5**, so I wanted to make new sentence like **sentence = [length:]** and iterate through it, but it is not going to iterate through new sentence, but the old one

Any Ideas? Big thanks

```
def reccurent():
    sentence = input("Enter the number:")
    nums = []
    number = ""

    for i in sentence:
        i = int(i)

        if i == 0:
            number += str(0)

        else:
            number += str(1)

            if len(number) == 1:
                nums.append(number)
                number = ""
                sentence = sentence[i:]

            else:
                length = len(number) + len(number) - 1
                word = str(sentence[:length])
                nums.append(word)
                number = ""
                sentence = sentence[length:]
    print(nums)

reccurent()
```

**Result**
Enter the number:0011000100

['00110', '1', '0100']

Process finished with exit code 0

**Should be**
['00110','00100']

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a modification based on the provided code.

```py
def reccurent():
    sentence = input("Enter the number:")
    nums = []
    number = ""
    
    # Define parameters to save the cursor offset position
    offset = 0
    for index, i in enumerate(sentence):

        # Skip the value before the cursor
        if index < offset:
            continue

        number += i
        if i != "0":

            if len(number) == 1:
                nums.append(number)
                offset = index + 1
            else:
                length = len(number) * 2 - 1
                word = sentence[offset: offset + length]
                nums.append(word)
                offset += length
            number = ""

    print(nums)
    
reccurent()
```

```
Enter the number:0011000100
['00110', '00100']
```